# Hyperlink in yahoo mail is not clickable

Tags: php, wordpress, yahoo, yahoo-mail

i am using following php code to send email to different mailing servers in wordpress.

```
home_url value =  http://ipaddress/website/

$url= home_url()."/?page_id=309&pin=".$pin;
 $to=$email;
 $subject="Registration Successful ! ";

 $password=rand(10000, 99999);

 $mess .="<p>Dear ".$name .",</p><p></p>";
 $mess .="<p>Please find link below to active your account. </p><p></p>"; 
 $mess .="<p></p>".$url."<p></p>";
 $mess .="<p><a href=' ".$url." '>".$url."</a></p><p></p>";
 $mess .="<p> Thanks, </p><p></p>";
 $mess .=" <p>Test Support Team </p><p></p>";
 //$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = ".$chrst. "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $from_name = get_bloginfo('name');

 $from_email = get_option('opt_glocal_site_email');

 if ($from_email) {

  $headers .= 'From: '.$from_name.' <'.$from_email.'>'. "\r\n";

 } else {

  $headers .= 'From: '.$from_name. "\r\n";

 }

 $send = mail ($to, $subject, $mess, $headers);
```

it sends account activation hyperlink to user but the issue is that hyperlink is not clickable in yahoo mail.

same code sends email to gmail,hotmail perfectly and link is clickable any one guide me what could be the issue.

**Inspect Element in yahoo for that link:**

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="return theMainWindow.showLinkWarning(this)" class="removed-link" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1411592352265_2952">http://ipaddress/website/?page_id=309</a>
```

****Note:** i am already using "http://" with href attribute.**

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is on spam folder? In any case i've seen this before with queried urls `?foo` which were solved with rewrites. It seems yahoo might not like parameters in url.

Comment: I tested your code using standard variables replacements for `home_url()` and `$from_name` and `$from_email` and got back the Email with clickable link. Something else is causing this, probably in WordPress itself.

Comment: If home_url value really is =  http: // ipaddress / website / and really is $url= home_url()."/?page_id=309&pin=".$pin; Your sending a link like this: http: // ipaddress / website // ?page_id=309&pin=... You have two slashes in the middle. Yahoo might not like that? I have a feeling this is just a typo though. (random spacing was so it wouldn't be turned into a hyperlink)

Comment: @Blizzardengle I just tested that theory and I still got back an Email with a clickable link.

Comment: Clickable where? Gmail is a magician with doing its own thing (fixing code) Yahoo not so much. What is all this <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="return theMainWindow.showLinkWarning(this)" class="removed-link" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1411592352265_2952">http://ipaddress/website/?page_id=309</a>? That too may be upsetting Yahoo OR TO BE HONEST I think it could be a header issue. Is the From address from the actual server sending the mail? Does it know your sending an HTML email? Could be stripping it and showing only text.

Comment: See here: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ Your missing a MIME version in your headers. These are basic headers too. Yahoo may be wanting more advanced ones.

Comment: guys thanks for putting some light on this issue, yes i just noticed email is being delivered in spam folder where link is not clickable, when i mark it safe and same email link gets clickable in inbox.is there any way to make link clickable in spam folder as well.

Answer (score 3):

When you send an email to a yahoo email address, their servers will wreck your links if you do not include rel="nofollow". I just had this issue when trying to do emails through wordpress.

revised version of your code should look like this:

```
$mess .="<p><a rel="nofollow" href=' ".$url." '>".$url."</a></p><p></p>";
```

I assume this is yahoo trying to stop people from getting paid links off of crawlers.
If you implement that line of code then your links should work in yahoo.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to change link from http to https like this

```
<a href="https://yoursite.com"></a>
```

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stripslashes()` to body of your email to strip extra slashes and then see if it works.I had a similar issue and `stripslashes()` worked perfectly for me

```
 $mess=stripslashes($mess);
```